How to tune query performance with OR filter and additional filter on a joined table
I have a quite simple 2-table setup in MySQL: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9w2NVHHXDQYssdWQskX1xJ/6
CREATE TABLE tblLetter (
              id int, 
              created datetime,
              expire datetime);

CREATE TABLE tblRecipient (
              id int,
              letterId int, 
              userId int,
              street varchar(50));

insert into tblLetter (id, created, expire) values (1, NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval 2 day));
insert into tblRecipient (id, letterId, userId, street) values (1, 1, 234, 's1');
insert into tblRecipient (id, letterId, userId, street) values (2, 1, 235, 's2');

insert into tblLetter (id, created, expire) values (2, NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval 2 day));
insert into tblRecipient (id, letterId, userId, street) values (3, 2, 234, 's3');

And the query.
SELECT DISTINCT L.id, L.created
  FROM tblRecipient R
  JOIN tblLetter L ON L.id = R.letterId
 WHERE (R.userId = 234 OR R.street = 's2') AND L.expire > NOW()
 ORDER BY L.created desc limit 100; 

I am struggling to find the most effective query/index setup to get the results with best possible performance. tblLetter has ~5 million rows, tblRecipient is ~4 times larger. For users which have small amount of letters it works very well. For users with a few hundred thousand letters assigned I can't get below ~1.5 second for each part of the OR, so totaling to around 3 seconds to get all the letter IDs.
I have tried various approaches with joins, left joins, subquery in where and more. I tried executing 2 separate queries to avoid the OR but there is no significant improvement. Both tables have some indexes, but I don't want to include them here as they include more columns and clutter the picture. The optimizer seems to always use some kind of index_merge. Can it be avoided? What indexes in theory should I add to both tables to get the best performance here - assuming we are desiging these tables from scratch? Is it possible that with this data model it can't get any faster bc the server has to traverse all (few hundred thousand) rows assigned to a specific user to filter on the other table column (expired)?

I would suggest adding the following indexes alter table tblLetter add index id_exp_cre(id,expire,created);
alter table tblRecipient add index lett_usrid_st (letterId,userId,street);
alter table tblRecipient add index lett_st(letterId,street); .  Try and use union all /union instead of  the or part and post the execution plan after

Does your published query represent your intent (which you haven't stated) given that it doesn't show the letter id and you can't distinguish between 2 letters with the same creation date.

@P.Salmon I don't exactly understand what you mean. The query intent is to get N most recent letters which have not expired and that belong to a user. The "belong" condition includes userID or the street address.

There are a couple of ways to speed things up.  I think the best would be
SELECT  L.id, L.created
    FROM  (
        ( SELECT R.letterId WHERE R.userId = 234  FROM tblRecipient R )
        UNION DISTINCT
        ( SELECT R.letterId WHERE R.street = 's2' FROM tblRecipient R )
          ) AS RR
    JOIN  tblLetter L  ON L.id = RR.letterId
    WHERE L.expire > NOW()
    ORDER BY  L.created desc
    limit  100;

with
tblRecipient:  INDEX(userId, letterId)
tblRecipient:  INDEX(street, letterId)
tblLetter:  PRIMARY KEY(id)  -- I assume you have this

Note:  A composite index starting with the PRIMARY KEY column(s) is futile -- it may as well simply use the data's BTree.
